# std::exception using message from local object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception

Is the following code safely throwing an exception with custom message?

```
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  try {
    std::ostringstream msg;
    msg << "give me " << 5;
    throw std::exception(msg.str().c_str());
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "exception: " << e.what();
  }
}
```

With VC++-2008 this gives:

```
exception: give me 5
```

But now I wonder why the message "give me 5" from the local object `msg` is still available in the catch-block? By the time the message is printed both the stream- and the temporary string-object should have been deleted? Btw: This way of generating a message for an exception seems also to work accross several functions and also if new memory is allocated in the catch-block before printing the exception.

Or is it necessary to define a custom exception class with a std::string member in order to safely keep the message until printing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's perfectly safe. The constructor that takes a C string as a single parameter makes a copy of the string. The constructor that takes a C string and a length parameter allow you to specify no memory be allocated and stores a pointer to the string (the length parameter is ignored).

Note that these two constructors are extensions to the `std::exception` class and are not standard. Also be aware that the constructor that takes a C string as a single parameter is not marked as explicit.

Comment: You may also want to read boost article on exceptions: http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html ,the advice they give in particular points 3 and 4: Don't embed a std::string object, Format the what() message on demand

Comment: Great suggestion but I don't see how points 3 and 4 are particular to the question.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Taking my question word for word the boost link seems off topic. But I ran into this question/problem because I was not aware of the considerations pointed out there. When following above mentioned points 3 and 4 my question becomes superfluous. This is a very valuable hint for me. Up to now I have avoided defining my own exception classes (in favor of VC`s std::exception). Thanks to your answer I am assured that I do not have an immediate problem. Thanks to the boost link I will consider using custom exception classes from now on to avoid "premature formatting".

Comment: Yeah I think I was taking it too literally and split a hair ;) My apologies.

Answer (score 4):

### It's OK.

Per §15.1/3:

> Throwing an exception copy-initializes (8.5, 12.8) a temporary object,
>   called the exception object.

and §15.1/4:

> The memory for the exception object is allocated in an unspecified
>   way, except as noted in 3.7.4.1. If a handler exits by rethrowing,
>   control is passed to another handler for the same exception. The
>   exception object is destroyed after either the last remaining active
>   handler for the exception exits by any means other than rethrowing...

so after `throw expression`:

the *expression* will be copied (new object will be created by copy constructor) and you shouldn't worry about the local object.

About the `msg` and `const char*` which you're worrying... here is Microsoft's implementation:

```
exception::exception(const char * const & _What)
: _Mywhat(NULL), _Mydofree(false)
{
   _Copy_str(_What);
 //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

void exception::_Copy_str(const char * _What)
{
   if (_What != NULL)
   {
      const size_t _Buf_size = strlen(_What) + 1;
      _Mywhat = static_cast<char *>(malloc(_Buf_size));
       if (_Mywhat != NULL)
       {
         _CRT_SECURE_STRCPY(const_cast<char *>(_Mywhat), _Buf_size, _What);
       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         _Mydofree = true;
       }
   }
 }
```

It copies the `_What` not just storing the pointer.

Comment: I was worried by VC's version of `std::exception` which only holds a char pointer. But it seems that the underlying char array is copied by the construtor.

Comment: @coproc: Updated to make you comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not safe, because `std::exception` doesn't have a constructor taking a char* in the standard. You are using an MS extension. To make it portable and safe, use `std::runtime_error` instead, to which you can pass a `std::string` in the ctor.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `std::runtime_error`, I will use that from now on. I wondered why I did not have any troubles so far with VC's `std::exception` only holding a char pointer (and not a `std::string`). But it seems that VC's `std::exception` is creating its own copy of the char array.

Comment: It is safe, please see the other answers to this question. Being an extension does not make it unsafe to use just non-portable.

Comment: Unportable is unsafe. Moving to a different version or a different compiler could cause this code to compile but invoke undefined behaviour when run. Since there are portable replacements that do almost the same, why take chances?