# Information to store in exception object: providing strings in exception

Tags: c++, string, exception, memory-management

I would like to do something like

```
FileIn::FileIn(const char* filename)
    {
    handle=CreateFile(filename,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ
        ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

    if(handle==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
     // Base class ExceptionWinapi will call GetLastError();
        throw ExceptionWinapiFile(filename);
        }
    }
```

However, if the ExceptionWinapi does not copy filename, it will probably be invalid when it is time to catch the exception. But copy the filename would require a malloc (if the buffer is not fixed-length) which may fail. So where to store the string?

EDIT: To make it more clear, consider

```
#include <cstdio>

class Foo
    {
    public:
        Foo(const Foo& foo){printf("Foo copy\n");}
        Foo(){printf("Foo\n");}
        ~Foo(){printf("~Foo\n");}
    };

class TestExcep
    {
public:
        TestExcep(const Foo& bar):m_bar(bar){}
    private:
        Foo m_bar;
};

class Test
    {
    public:
        Test(const Foo& bar)
            {throw TestExcep(bar);}
};

int main()
    {
    try
        {
        Foo bar;
        Test a(bar);
        }
    catch(const TestExcep& excep)
        {
        printf("Error\n");
        return 1;
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

prints (comment added)

```
Foo
Foo copy
~Foo               <======Destroy old Foo after copy to the exception object!
Error
~Foo
```

EDIT 2: if  Foo(const Foo& foo){printf("Foo copy\n");} throws, then it is that exception that is cauch not the old one. This is also bad.

EDIT 3:

Useful parts of ExceptionWinapiFile

```
ExceptionWinapiFile(const char* filename)
    {
    m_length=streln(filename)+1;
    m_buffer=(char*)malloc(m_length*sizeof(char));
    if(m_buffer==NULL)
        {
        //The problem
        abort(); //????
        }
    memcpy(m_buffer,filename,m_length*sizeof(char));
    }
```

Also (the same problem again)

```
ExceptionWinapiFile(const ExceptionWinapiFile& e)
    {
    m_length=e.m_length;
    m_buffer=(char*)malloc(m_length*sizeof(char));
    if(m_buffer==NULL)
        {
        //The problem
        abort(); //????
        }
    memcpy(m_buffer,e.filename,m_length*sizeof(char));
    }
```

No problem in dtor, at least:

```
~ExceptionWinapiFile()
     {
     free(m_buffer);
     m_buffer=NULL; //As recommended by boost
     }
```

Comment: Why not using `std::string` and call its `.c_str()` method when a C version of the string is required. This way you don't have any malloc / copy to deal with. Use `=` to copy `string`s.

Comment: @Golgauth: If the exception object took a string object, it would require a call to std::string:s copy constructor, which may throw an exception and ... STOP! If it instead took a reference to a string (equivalent by just storing the char pointer), the problem is that the string will die before the exception has been cautch. So it does not solve the problem.

Comment: [I've answered a similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16678377/952747) There's no problem, it copies the `filename` to the exception object.

Comment: @M M. The problem araises when the object to throw is going to be created. I cannot create it without allocate space on the heap (or somewhere else) for filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just have to face the fact that creating an exception that holds a arbitrary-sized string will have to allocate memory, which may fail. The only thing you can do is mitigate.

First, the worst thing that can happen is that the throw sub-expression succeeds, but copying the exception to the exception storage throws. In this case, std::terminate is immediately called and you're screwed. You don't want that.

In practice, this is rarely a problem, because this copy will usually be elided, which means that there is no chance to throw. In addition, if you're using C++11, make sure your exception has a no-throw move constructor. It will be used in preference to the copy constructor, and so you don't risk an exception.

Second, the throw sub-expression itself may throw. If so, then the new exception will be thrown instead of the one you intended. In your case, if you have a std::string member in the exception class, you'll most likely get a std::bad_alloc exception instead of the ExceptionWinapiFile you wanted to throw. The question you have to ask yourself is, is this really a problem? If you're so low on memory that you can't allocate enough space for a filename, do you really still care about a file not being opened? Chances are it failed because of insufficient memory anyway, and if it hadn't failed, whatever you were about to do with the file would probably fail due to insufficient memory.

So unless you have very, very specific requirements, I say don't worry about it. Put the std::string member in there and you'll be fine.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly.  We already have an exception for out of memory (std::bad_alloc).  Other exception classes represent other situations--no need to worry about memory (within reason, of course).